# How to track focus of browser itself in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, focus, visibility, onblur

I'm implementing a pan feature where you can pan by holding spacebar and clicking to drag. Below is a simplified example of how my code works.

The problem is that if the browser itself loses focus before the spacebar is released, then the window is still listening for mousedown events and doesn't stop listening until the spacebar is pressed again and released.

I've read and added visibilitychange and blur, but these only fire when a different tab within the browser is selected, not when the browser itself loses focus.

Is there a way to track when the browser itself loses/regains focus?
Or is there a way to access a list of all currently pressed keys outside of an event listener?

If this is not possible, my users may just have to deal with it I guess.

```js
const spacebarDown = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === ' ') {
        const startPanning = e => {
            // some code to track mouse location
            const pan = e => {
                // some code to compare mouse location and apply translation to element
            }
            const stopPanning = e => {
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', pan);
            }
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', pan);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPanning);
        }
        const spacebarUp = ({ key }) => {
            if (key === ' ') window.removeEventListener('mousedown', startPanning);
        }
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', startPanning);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', spacebarUp);
        window.addEventListener('blur', spacebarUp);
        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', spacebarUp);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', spacebarDown);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the document has focus, try document.hasFocus();

Here's a more detailed explanation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_hasfocus.asp

The second Link has a live example, with code:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_hasfocus

**However, you cannot check if the browser itself (the application) has focus from the internet, that would be a security risk.**
Think of it this way: You should not be able to detect from the internet how any applicaion running locally on somebodys machine behaves.